# Query regarding setting ESP32 eFuses for restricting USB firmware access

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I am currently working on a project where I need to restrict the ability to read and write firmware through the USB interface on the ESP32. To achieve this, I have attempted to set the following eFuses for experimentation purposes: `UART_DOWNLOAD_DIS (BLOCK0)`, `DISABLE_DL_ENCRYPT (BLOCK0)`, and `DISABLE_DL_DECRYPT (BLOCK0)`. However, despite setting these eFuses, I am still able to burn code into the ESP32.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in identifying what might be causing this issue. Am I setting the correct eFuses for my requirement? If not, could you please advise me on the correct eFuses to set in order to prevent USB firmware access?

```
=== Run "summary" command ===
EFUSE_NAME (Block) Description  = [Meaningful Value] [Readable/Writeable] (Hex Value)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Calibration fuses:
BLK3_PART_RESERVE (BLOCK0):                        BLOCK3 partially served for ADC calibration data   = False R/W (0b0)
ADC_VREF (BLOCK0):                                 Voltage reference calibration                      = 1079 R/W (0b10011)

Config fuses:
XPD_SDIO_FORCE (BLOCK0):                           Ignore MTDI pin (GPIO12) for VDD_SDIO on reset     = False R/W (0b0)
XPD_SDIO_REG (BLOCK0):                             If XPD_SDIO_FORCE, enable VDD_SDIO reg on reset    = False R/W (0b0)
XPD_SDIO_TIEH (BLOCK0):                            If XPD_SDIO_FORCE & XPD_SDIO_REG                   = 1.8V R/W (0b0)
CLK8M_FREQ (BLOCK0):                               8MHz clock freq override                           = 54 R/W (0x36)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_CLK (BLOCK0):                       Override SD_CLK pad (GPIO6/SPICLK)                 = 0 R/W (0b00000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_Q (BLOCK0):                         Override SD_DATA_0 pad (GPIO7/SPIQ)                = 0 R/W (0b00000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_D (BLOCK0):                         Override SD_DATA_1 pad (GPIO8/SPID)                = 0 R/W (0b00000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_HD (BLOCK0):                        Override SD_DATA_2 pad (GPIO9/SPIHD)               = 0 R/W (0b00000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_CS0 (BLOCK0):                       Override SD_CMD pad (GPIO11/SPICS0)                = 0 R/W (0b00000)
DISABLE_SDIO_HOST (BLOCK0):                        Disable SDIO host                                  = False R/W (0b0)

Efuse fuses:
WR_DIS (BLOCK0):                                   Efuse write disable mask                           = 0 R/W (0x0000)
RD_DIS (BLOCK0):                                   Efuse read disable mask                            = 0 R/W (0x0)
CODING_SCHEME (BLOCK0):                            Efuse variable block length scheme
   = NONE (BLK1-3 len=256 bits) R/W (0b00)
KEY_STATUS (BLOCK0):                               Usage of efuse block 3 (reserved)                  = False R/W (0b0)

Identity fuses:
MAC (BLOCK0):                                      Factory MAC Address
   = 7c:9e:bd:45:7d:c0 (CRC 0x0d OK) R/W
MAC_CRC (BLOCK0):                                  CRC8 for factory MAC address                       = 13 R/W (0x0d)
CHIP_VER_REV1 (BLOCK0):                            Silicon Revision 1                                 = True R/W (0b1)
CHIP_VER_REV2 (BLOCK0):                            Silicon Revision 2                                 = False R/W (0b0)
WAFER_VERSION_MINOR (BLOCK0):                      WAFER VERSION MINOR                                = 0 R/W (0b00)
CHIP_PACKAGE (BLOCK0):                             Chip package identifier                            = 0 R/W (0b000)
CHIP_PACKAGE_4BIT (BLOCK0):                        Chip package identifier #4bit                      = 0 R/W (0b0)
MAC_VERSION (BLOCK3):                              Version of the MAC field                           = 0 R/W (0x00)
WAFER_VERSION_MAJOR (BLOCK0):                      calc WAFER VERSION MAJOR from CHIP_VER_REV1 and CH = 1 R/W (0b001)
                                                   IP_VER_REV2 and apb_ctl_date (read only)
PKG_VERSION (BLOCK0):                              calc Chip package = CHIP_PACKAGE_4BIT << 3 + CHIP_ = 0 R/W (0x0)
                                                   PACKAGE (read only)

Security fuses:
FLASH_CRYPT_CNT (BLOCK0):                          Flash encryption mode counter                      = 0 R/W (0b0000000)
UART_DOWNLOAD_DIS (BLOCK0):                        Disable UART download mode (ESP32 rev3 only)       = True R/W (0b1)
FLASH_CRYPT_CONFIG (BLOCK0):                       Flash encryption config (key tweak bits)           = 0 R/W (0x0)
CONSOLE_DEBUG_DISABLE (BLOCK0):                    Disable ROM BASIC interpreter fallback             = True R/W (0b1)
ABS_DONE_0 (BLOCK0):                               Secure boot V1 is enabled for bootloader image     = False R/W (0b0)
ABS_DONE_1 (BLOCK0):                               Secure boot V2 is enabled for bootloader image     = False R/W (0b0)
JTAG_DISABLE (BLOCK0):                             Disable JTAG                                       = False R/W (0b0)
DISABLE_DL_ENCRYPT (BLOCK0):                       Disable flash encryption in UART bootloader        = False R/W (0b0)
DISABLE_DL_DECRYPT (BLOCK0):                       Disable flash decryption in UART bootloader        = False R/W (0b0)
DISABLE_DL_CACHE (BLOCK0):                         Disable flash cache in UART bootloader             = False R/W (0b0)
BLOCK1 (BLOCK1):                                   Flash encryption key
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W
BLOCK2 (BLOCK2):                                   Secure boot key
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W
BLOCK3 (BLOCK3):                                   Variable Block 3
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W

Flash voltage (VDD_SDIO) determined by GPIO12 on reset
```

Thank you for your time and expertise.